# Is there an integration between salesforce and infor sun systems?

Tags: api, integration, connected-apps

I am looking to pull data from Infor Sun on a regular basis into Salesforce. Is there an existing integration for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of any etl tools which has api driven methods of integration with source & target system . There are some tools like DBsync , dell bhoomi which does integration between financial systems & salesforce crm

I see that infor sun is a financial accounting solution & certainly one of these ETL systems can help you achieve your process